# Does "a couple of hours" equal "two hours"?

Tags: word-usage, phrases

> I left the bag in the hall and Robert and I went into the living room where we talked for **a couple of hours**.

Does **a couple of hours** equal **two hours**? Or it simply represents **several hours**?

Answer (score 2):

If you consult a dictionary, it will likely state that "couple" means "two" *or* "several".

"a couple of hours" means *roughly* two hours.